# Looking in file directories in Lua

Tags: csv, lua, path, conv-neural-network, torch

I'm trying to adapt some code for a research project but have never previously coded in Lua. As a result I'm not sure how the paths and loading work. I have these CSV files that contain information of proteins within them and the plan is to convert them into images for a neural network. However I am not sure what properties and file directories to put these CSV files into. Does anyone have any insight?

```
local M={}

require 'paths';
torch.manualSeed(123)

local function LoadCSV(proteinName)
    local file = io.open(proteinName, 'r')
    local header = file:read()
    local dat = {}
    for l in file:lines() do
        local row = l:split(',')
        table.insert(dat,row)
    end
    return torch.Tensor(dat)
end

function M.Maper(cancerType)
    local pros = paths.dir('Data/' .. cancerType)
    os.execute("mkdir " .. "Data/" .. cancerType .. "_Map")
    table.remove(pros,1)
    table.remove(pros,1)
    table.sort(pros)
    local n = #pros
    
    for i=1,n,3 do
        local tens = {}
        print(pros[i])
        for j=1,3 do
            local map = torch.zeros(16,200,200)
            gene = LoadCSV('Data/' .. cancerType .. '/' .. pros[i+j-1])
            atoms = gene:size(1)
            for a=1,atoms do
                --print(gene[a][17] , gene[a][18])
                map[{ {}, {math.min(gene[a][17]+1,200)}, {math.min(gene[a][18]+1,200)} }] = gene[{ {a}, {1,16} }]
            end
            tens[j] = map:clone()
        end
        torch.save('Data/' .. cancerType .. '_Map/' .. pros[i]:sub(1,4) .. '.dat',tens)
    end
end

local function Shuffle(...)
    local args = {...}
    local n = #args[1]
    local count = 0
    count=(torch.type(n)=='number' and n or n[1]) 
    for t=1,count do
        local k = math.random(count)
        for i,v in ipairs{...} do
            v[t],v[k] = v[k],v[t]
        end
    end
    return {...}
end

function M.DataCollect(positive,negative,neutral)
    local posProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. positive)
    table.remove(posProtein,1)
    table.remove(posProtein,1)
    local negProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. negative)
    table.remove(negProtein,1)
    table.remove(negProtein,1)
    --local nutProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. neutral)
    --table.remove(nutProtein,1)
    --table.remove(nutProtein,1)
    local label = torch.zeros(#posProtein+#negProtein)
    local allProtein = {}
    local index=1
    for i=1,#posProtein do
        table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. positive .. '/' .. posProtein[i])
        label[index]=1
        index=index+1
    end

    for i=1,#negProtein do
        table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. negative .. '/' .. negProtein[i])
    end

    --for i=1,#nutProtein do
    --  table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. neutral .. '/' .. nutProtein[i])
    --end

    _ = Shuffle(allProtein,label)

    return allProtein,label
end

function M.Slice(tbl, first, last, step)
  local sliced = {}

  for i = first or 1, last or #tbl, step or 1 do
    sliced[#sliced+1] = tbl[i]
  end

  return sliced
end

function M.Fetch(names,h,w)
  local pros = torch.Tensor(3,#names,16,h,w)
  local threads = require 'threads'
  local pool = threads.Threads(4)
  for i=1,#names do
    pool:addjob(function()
      local temp = torch.load(names[i])
      return i,temp
    end,
    function(id,pr)
    --print(pr,pros:size())
      pros[{ {1}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[1]:clone()
      pros[{ {2}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[2]:clone()
      pros[{ {3}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[3]:clone()
    end
    )
  end
  pool:synchronize()
  pool:terminate()
  return pros
end

function M.Dataset(proteins,labels,meani,stdvi)
    local dataset = {}
    dataset.data = proteins
    dataset.label = labels
    setmetatable(dataset,{__index = function(t, i) 
                    return {
                        t.data[i],
                        t.label[i]
                    } 
                end}
    );
    
    function dataset:size() 
        return self.data:size(1) 
    end
    
    local mean = torch.zeros(16)
    local stdv  = torch.zeros(16)

     if meani~=nil then
       for i=1,16 do
       dataset.data:select(3, i):add(-meani[i])
       dataset.data:select(3, i):div(stdvi[i])
       end
     else   
         for i=1,16 do
         mean[i] = dataset.data:select(3, i):mean() 
         dataset.data:select(3, i):add(-mean[i])
         stdv[i] = dataset.data:select(3, i):std()
         dataset.data:select(3, i):div(stdv[i])
         end
     end

    return dataset,mean,stdv
end

return M
local M={}

require 'paths';
torch.manualSeed(123)

local function LoadCSV(proteinName)
    local file = io.open(proteinName, 'r')
    local header = file:read()
    local dat = {}
    for l in file:lines() do
        local row = l:split(',')
        table.insert(dat,row)
    end
    return torch.Tensor(dat)
end

function M.Maper(cancerType)
    local pros = paths.dir('Data/' .. cancerType)
    os.execute("mkdir " .. "Data/" .. cancerType .. "_Map")
    table.remove(pros,1)
    table.remove(pros,1)
    table.sort(pros)
    local n = #pros
    
    for i=1,n,3 do
        local tens = {}
        print(pros[i])
        for j=1,3 do
            local map = torch.zeros(16,200,200)
            gene = LoadCSV('Data/' .. cancerType .. '/' .. pros[i+j-1])
            atoms = gene:size(1)
            for a=1,atoms do
                --print(gene[a][17] , gene[a][18])
                map[{ {}, {math.min(gene[a][17]+1,200)}, {math.min(gene[a][18]+1,200)} }] = gene[{ {a}, {1,16} }]
            end
            tens[j] = map:clone()
        end
        torch.save('Data/' .. cancerType .. '_Map/' .. pros[i]:sub(1,4) .. '.dat',tens)
    end
end

local function Shuffle(...)
    local args = {...}
    local n = #args[1]
    local count = 0
    count=(torch.type(n)=='number' and n or n[1]) 
    for t=1,count do
        local k = math.random(count)
        for i,v in ipairs{...} do
            v[t],v[k] = v[k],v[t]
        end
    end
    return {...}
end

function M.DataCollect(positive,negative,neutral)
    local posProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. positive)
    table.remove(posProtein,1)
    table.remove(posProtein,1)
    local negProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. negative)
    table.remove(negProtein,1)
    table.remove(negProtein,1)
    --local nutProtein = paths.dir('Data/' .. neutral)
    --table.remove(nutProtein,1)
    --table.remove(nutProtein,1)
    local label = torch.zeros(#posProtein+#negProtein)
    local allProtein = {}
    local index=1
    for i=1,#posProtein do
        table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. positive .. '/' .. posProtein[i])
        label[index]=1
        index=index+1
    end

    for i=1,#negProtein do
        table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. negative .. '/' .. negProtein[i])
    end

    --for i=1,#nutProtein do
    --  table.insert(allProtein, 'Data/' .. neutral .. '/' .. nutProtein[i])
    --end

    _ = Shuffle(allProtein,label)

    return allProtein,label
end

function M.Slice(tbl, first, last, step)
  local sliced = {}

  for i = first or 1, last or #tbl, step or 1 do
    sliced[#sliced+1] = tbl[i]
  end

  return sliced
end

function M.Fetch(names,h,w)
  local pros = torch.Tensor(3,#names,16,h,w)
  local threads = require 'threads'
  local pool = threads.Threads(4)
  for i=1,#names do
    pool:addjob(function()
      local temp = torch.load(names[i])
      return i,temp
    end,
    function(id,pr)
    --print(pr,pros:size())
      pros[{ {1}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[1]:clone()
      pros[{ {2}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[2]:clone()
      pros[{ {3}, {id}, {}, {}, {} }] = pr[3]:clone()
    end
    )
  end
  pool:synchronize()
  pool:terminate()
  return pros
end

function M.Dataset(proteins,labels,meani,stdvi)
    local dataset = {}
    dataset.data = proteins
    dataset.label = labels
    setmetatable(dataset,{__index = function(t, i) 
                    return {
                        t.data[i],
                        t.label[i]
                    } 
                end}
    );
    
    function dataset:size() 
        return self.data:size(1) 
    end
    
    local mean = torch.zeros(16)
    local stdv  = torch.zeros(16)

     if meani~=nil then
       for i=1,16 do
       dataset.data:select(3, i):add(-meani[i])
       dataset.data:select(3, i):div(stdvi[i])
       end
     else   
         for i=1,16 do
         mean[i] = dataset.data:select(3, i):mean() 
         dataset.data:select(3, i):add(-mean[i])
         stdv[i] = dataset.data:select(3, i):std()
         dataset.data:select(3, i):div(stdv[i])
         end
     end

    return dataset,mean,stdv
end

return M
```

Comment: you put the file into directories that make sense for you. it is not quite clear what you want to know. we don't know the contents of those file so how can we help you with where to store them? please read [ask]

Comment: Do you mean, you're not sure where your code is executing from? and as such it cant seem to find your `Data` folder?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like this is a library meant to be required either within a Lua script or interactively from within the interpreter. In either case, the interpreter should be started from the directory containing the Lua project. This directory should also contain a `Data/` sub-directory. The `Data/` directory should contain further directories named after types of cancer which contain the CSV files.
Eg:

```
path/to/lua/project/
└── Data
    ├── cancer1
    │   ├── protein1.csv
    │   └── protein2.csv
    └── cancer2
        ├── protein1.csv
        ├── protein2.csv
        └── protein3.csv
```

You might, for example, try:

```
cd path/to/lua/project
lua your_script.lua
```

Beyond that, I really can't say much about your project.

I can possibly clarify a few strange looking lines -- you say you're not sure how "paths" work. In the library code you've shown, `require "paths"` runs the code from a file named `paths.lua` in the global scope of the shown library. The file is probably in the same directory as the rest of your code, but could be anywhere in the directories listed in `package.path`.

This (`paths`) is not a standard Lua library, but it looks simple enough. It seems that `paths.dir` is a function which returns a table containing the contents of a directory as strings. The odd lines where `table.remove` is called twice in a row are almost certainly taking these directory contents and removing the hidden `.` and `..` files (though it may be worth noting it is done very inefficiently).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. The code above was taken from https://github.com/tavanaei/Cancer-Suppressor-Gene-Deep-Learning     however, paths as a file was never included in the github folder. Is there a way to replicate the file? Or is there something I'm missing throughout the rest of the lua files?

Comment: Hi, I have never used Torch before, but it looks like paths is a core library in Torch ([github link](https://github.com/torch/paths)). The installation instructions for Torch ([here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html)) mention that the given command will install the paths library via LuaRocks (a Lua package manager). It sounds like you installed Torch, but not the other libraries. If you have LuaRocks installed, you can install paths with the command `luarocks install paths`. Here is the package page: [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/modules/develcuy/paths).